# Getting one line from Arduino Serial Port C++ Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, serial-port, arduino-uno

I have a simple Win32 Console application in Visual Studio 2013 that reads from an Arduino light dependent resistor in a loop. It outputs to the serial port (USB) like this (with line breaks between each reading from the Arduino):

058

058

057

058

058

057

However, in Visual Studio 2013 when I convert this incoming data to a usable integer for use elsewhere in my C++ program, I get these numbers in a jumbled fashion, such as:

580

8

5

805

0

057

Obviously these are the values 057 and 058 just jumbled up. Is there any way to get read just one line at a time and turn that into a simple integer? 
Something like the C#:
MessageBox.Show(serialPort1.ReadLine())
...but in C++ console app?'
I would love this to happen:

int Serialint = 058

int Serialint = 058

int Serialint = 057

instead of:

int Serialint = 705

int Serialint = 5

int Serialint = 7

Here is my C++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "SerialClass.h"    // Library described at http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

Serial* Arduino = new Serial("\\\\.\\COM3");    // read Arduino on COM3

if (Arduino->IsConnected())
    cout << "We're connected... nice";

char incomingData[256] = "";            // don't forget to pre-allocate memory
int dataLength = 3;
int readResult = 0;

int serialRXint; // for converting char array to int with atoi

while (Arduino->IsConnected())
{

    readResult = Arduino->ReadData(incomingData, dataLength);
    serialRXint = atoi(incomingData); //to convert char serial data from Arduino into a usable integer      
    //cout << incomingData << " converted from char* to int is: " << serialRXint << endl;
    cout << serialRXint << endl;
    Sleep(1);
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I solved this problem using synchronous communication between pc and arduino

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ccr, how did you do the synchronous communication between pc and arduino?

Comment: send data from arduino in every t ms, and in pc read serialport every t ms.